# How long did it take before the Hawley–Smoot Tariffs reached their peak effect on US growth?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, united-states, tariffs, economic-history

I understand that this may still be a contentious issue, but are there some estimates how long it took before the Hawley–Smoot Tariffs impacted US growth significantly and/or how long it took for them to have their maximum impact on US growth (of course relative to some counterfactual scenarios).

And if somehow the same source(s) estimate the [time lagged] effects of the earlier 1922 tariffs, which were [also significant](https://www.economist.com/christmas-specials/2008/12/18/the-battle-of-smoot-hawley) tariff-wise... that would be also interesting to know.